# Xaml binding for radio/checkbox to toggle between imperial/metric

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

Pretty much as the title states, I'm grabbing some values from a Db, which are all in Km, but I want to implement a converter which I can toggle between Miles or Kilometers, and want to bind which is displayed to either a checkbox, or a radio button group, whichever is easiest (Radio would be preferred).

I'm thinking I can just use an `IValueConverter` rather than an `IMultiValueConverter`, and the Convert/ConvertBack methods, as the default will be Kilometers, but I don't know how to call the ConvertBack method. Or I could pass true/false as the ConverterParameter depending on whether I want Km/Miles displayed.

But either way I'm not sure how to hook up the Xaml Binding on either method (I know how to do a standard value converter binding, but not the extra flumff needed.

Any hints appreciated.

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <RadioButton Content="Km" GroupName="rdBtnGrpValue" IsChecked="True" />
    <RadioButton Content="Miles" GroupName="rdBtnGrpValue" />
</StackPanel>
```

And:

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding EquatorialCircumference, Converter={StaticResource KmMiConv}, StringFormat='{}{0:0,0.0}'}" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the MVVM pattern, and are using a view-model as your `DataContext`, you could use a `Mode=TwoWay` binding between the `RadioButton`s and a boolean property in the view-model, something like `bool ConvertToImperial { get; set; }`.

Your actual conversion can occur in the getter for the `EquatorialCircumference` property. If `ConvertToImperial` is `true`, return the value in miles, otherwise return the value in kilometres.

Then, for the `TextBox`, you can simply bind it to the `EquatorialCircumference` property, and the value displayed will be in the selected unit.

You will, however, need to raise a property change notification for any properties whose values are affected by a change in units.

Comment: This is the way I ended up going, though had to expand it a little as my Models had sub-models which needed to be affected by the change as well.